# R: Fable - forecasting hierarchical time series with transformation

Tags: r, forecasting, multilevel-analysis

I have a hierarchical time series, with two sub-series that have significantly different behaviours. One subseries would definitely benefit from Box-Cox transformation to stabilise the variance.

Is there a way to do a hierarchical forecast in fable with transformations applied to subseries and still get a consistent forecast in the end? Intuitively, it seems like a non-trivial task to me, but I would be more than happy to be proven wrong.

Could anyone point me to papers or books that cover this?